# how to use SAP B1 screen painter form fields in C#

Tags: c#, sapb1

I have created a form using screen painter and save as xml in my project file. how may I use this form fields i.e. button, edittext etc in C#.

Comment: Did you created a C# WPF or Window Forms project?

Comment: Yes I have created and also load xml form in it

Comment: Hi, although *yes* is a valid answer, @Gaterde want's to know which technology you are using: `WinForms` or `WPF`.

Comment: I am using WinForms

Answer (score 0):

In screen painter, give a unique ID to each form object, e.g. UserName for the edittext below

[image]

In C# initialize your control, e.g.

```
SAPbouiCOM.Item oItem = null;
private SAPbouiCOM.EditText _userName;

oItem = _form.Items.Item("UserName");
_userName = oItem.Specific; 
_userName.Value = "";
```

There are examples in SAP B1 SDK that show how to do this once installed. E.g for my path

C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\SAP Business One SDK\Samples\COM UI\CSharp

Look at example 3